# http.get returns different response from localhost and from server when fetching gzipped file

Tags: javascript, http, ionic2, get, gzip

### Problem

I am having trouble with `http.get` in Ionic 3 / Angular when trying to `.get` gzipped json file.
When I test on localhost, I am getting the gzipped content, but when I deploy an app to web, response is already unpacked.
This can be seen by inspecting `result.byteLength`, which returns length of packed file when on localhost, and returns length of unpacked file when on web. (Also, on inspection of the returned ArrayBuffer, it is obvious that in one case content is gzipped, and in other case result is already unpacked.)

### Question

So – is there a way to `.get` a gzipped file in a way that would not depend on where the asset is hosted?

I would prefer to always get unpacked json content, but I don't mind inflating the response myself (I am using [pako](https://github.com/nodeca/pako) library), but I need to know if response is already unpacked or not.

### Code snippet:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

...

  this.http.get("./assets/dict.json.gz", { responseType: 'arraybuffer' } ).subscribe(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result.byteLength); // <<<!!! not same when getting response from localhost and from server!
        // do something with response...
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error("Dictionary load failure: ");
        console.log(err);
      },
      () => {
        // console.log("loadDict done");
      });
```

Comment: What are headers returned by both servers in this response ?

Comment: `Server Response Headers: 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2018 16:13:35 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 902506
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Tue, 20 Feb 2018 11:24:36 GMT
ETag: "dc56a-565a30e354500"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Loopia-Node: 172.22.223.33`

Comment: `Localhost Response Headers: 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Tue, 20 Feb 2018 16:25:28 GMT
ETag: W/"dc57c-161b408c478"
Content-Type: application/gzip
Content-Length: 902524
Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2018 16:30:33 GMT
Connection: keep-alive`